# How to implement clock into Program Counter?

Tags: hdl

I am trying to create a program counter with logic gates. I got the logic done but I'm not sure where I should connect the clock.

[image: what I did so far]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... where I should connect the clock.

This is because your circuit will not work:

Let's say "*inc in*" is true, "*load in*" is false and "*reset in*" is false.

Then the value of "*out Out*" is the output of the "*inc16*" element.

And the output of the "*inc16*" element is the value of "*out Out*" plus 1.

This means that the value of "*out Out*" is calculated as:

```
inc16 = out_Out + 1
out_Out = inc16
```

Or:

```
out_Out = out_Out + 1
```

This line has to be read like a mathematical equation, not like a variable assignment in a programming language:

And because the equation has no solution, the circuit won't work.

You have to introduce some delay element (a register made of flip-flops) into your circuit. This delay element will be controlled by the "*Clock in*" input:

Whenever there is a pulse at "*Clock in*", the input of the delay element will be copied to it's output.

The equations could then look like this (there are different possibilities):

```
inc16 = delay_Out + 1
out_Out = inc16
delay_In = out_Out
delay_Out = delay_In;
```

Or:

```
out_Out = out_Out + 1;
```

The first three lines are again read like mathematical equations; however, the two lines ending with a semi-colon ("`;`") are meant like a variable assignment in a programming language (such as C, C++ or Java) that takes place when there is a pulse from the "*Clock in*" input.

Here is EV3's solution (thanks for the edit):

[image: full answer]